# How to Pass Data to Card list in flutter through constructor ? I have Tried these things, result and want is attached

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-card

How to achieve this kind of format ? i am really confused how to do in flutter?

This is the result what i have acheived so far [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBLeb.jpg).

and

This is what i actually looking for [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xWY8.jpg)
, where i can add as many values as i want , but in card view format.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) => Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 5.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 55.0,
                          height: 55.0,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://thechive.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/4a0dd2313a49cba8381ee0ba33008514.jpg?quality=85&strip=info&w=650"),
                          ),
                          ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                        customGroupText("abc", "10/10/2010"),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 10.0),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder (
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Join Now", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the class where i will made my constructor .

```
class customGroupText extends StatelessWidget {
  String names;
  String datess;
  customGroupText(this.names,this.datess);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            names,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        Text(
            datess,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easily can be done by tile

```
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.android),
    title: Text('My title'),
    subtitle: Text('my sub title'),
    trailing: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.print),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

BTW thanks for marking answers to your questions as answered!!!!